# Apportable Error compiling Xcode Project

Tags: compiler-errors, apportable

Thanks in advance for anyones help. Like everyone else I am trying to expedite my android app as quick as possible by compiling my iOs app. I receive this error:

FAILED PATH = ..../TechBook/PhotoBrowserOverlayView.m' -o '/Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/corp.laserpros.com/TechBook/Users/MacUser/Desktop/EPUB & APPS/Mobile App/AppleApp/NEW BUILD STRUCTURE/LPI_TECH_APP_V1.3_BUILD_1.1.4 copy 2/TechBook/AGPhotoBrowserOverlayView.m.o' -MD -MF '/Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/corp.laserpros.com/TechBook/Users/MacUser/Desktop/EPUB & APPS/Mobile App/AppleApp/NEW BUILD STRUCTURE/LPI_TECH_APP_V1.3_BUILD_1.1.4 copy 2/TechBook/AGPhotoBrowserOverlayView.m.o'.d 
/Users/MacUser/Desktop/EPUB & APPS/Mobile App/AppleApp/NEW BUILD STRUCTURE/LPI_TECH_APP_V1.3_BUILD_1.1.4 copy 2/TechBook/AGPhotoBrowserOverlayView.m:380:23: error: no visible @interface for 'CALayer' declares the selector 'insertSublayer:atIndex:'
                [_sharingView.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0];
                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
Error: command failed: /Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/toolchain/macosx/ninja/ninja --no-strip-ansi-escapes -j 8 /Users/MacUser/.apportable/SDK/Build/android-armeabi-debug/TechBook/TechBook-debug.apk

I don't understand because in the code:

```
interface PhotoBrowserOverlayView () {

    CAGradientLayer *_gradientLayer;
}
```

any help is appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler is complaining about a missing selector `insertSublayer:atIndex:` on `CALayer`  - this is being used on your  `_sharingView`  ivar in code you haven't shown here.

The reason for the error is `CALayer` is not fully implemented in apportable.  See the discussion in the apportable forum:

http://forum.apportable.com/t/core-ios-sdk-compatibility/31/3

http://forum.apportable.com/t/core-ios-sdk-compatibility/31/5

Comment: thanks that answers that question. Actually by commenting out the line  [_sharingView.layer insertSublayer:_gradientLayer atIndex:0]; i was able to get my app to load on a android device however that introduces a whole new issue. A question for another time. Thanks for your answer.